# Show only errors with pylint and syntastic in vim

Tags: python, vim, pylint, syntastic

How to use synstastic in vim to display only pylint error messages? I basically want the output of `pylint -E` to be used as source for syntastic. I tried to configure syntastic in my `.vimrc` with:

```
 let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['python', 'pylint -E']
```

which did not work. Also, I tried to configure pylint to show only errors without the -E flag via the following lines in my `.pylintrc`:

```
disable=all
enable=E
```

which seems to be only `disable=all`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works by disabling all other categories in `.pylintrc`:

```
disable=C, F, I, R, W
```

Comment: If you are to add this line only just remember to add [MESSAGES CONTROL] above that line. (For those who are googling in hurry :) )

Answer (score 7):

Wanted to add a different type of answer, since I was able to get this to work:

Adding arguments to `syntastic` works a little differently than as mentioned by OP. Instead, what I have is, in my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pylint']  "" or ['flake8', 'pylint'], etc
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_args = '-E'
"" to show it accepts a string of args, also:
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_args = '--rcfile=/path/to/rc -E'
```

Answer (score 3):

from https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = {
        \ "!level":  "errors",
        \ "type":    "style",
        \ "regex":   '.*',
        \ "file:p":  '.*' }
```

That would ignore all style warnings in all file types.
Note the ! in !level. You can also put 'type':['style', 'syntax'], but in general it's not a good idea to ignore syntax warnings.